# TiddlyServer on Azure App Services not saving tiddlers and not uploading files

Tags: azure, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

Inspired by the [Tutorial for Running Node.js TW5 on Microsoft Azure for Free](https://dynalist.io/d/VA2eH2p8x8-beDiyYJV04YA9) I'd like to host [TiddlyServer](https://arlen22.github.io/tiddlyserver/) on Azure. As a first attempt I followed the instructions in the tutorial and was successful in getting Node.js TW5 working on Azure.

I deployed TiddlyServer on my desktop without any difficulty.

Then I did the following  to get TiddlyServer running on Azure, but got stuck. What am I doing wrong?

1. I downloaded **tiddlyserver-2.2.0-alpha-3.zip** and **tiddlywiki-production-5.1.22.zip** from [TiddlyServer's Github](https://github.com/Arlen22/TiddlyServer/releases) and placed the tiddlyserver files in the wwwroot, and the tiddlywiki-production files in the tiddlywiki folder. I also created a data folder and I moved my tiddlers there.

[image]

2. I edited the package.json adding "scripts" to the end:

[image]

3. I edited the settings.json with client keys, _datafoldertarget and bindInfo

[image]

4. I deployed to Azure
5. I navigated to the web page and logged in following the TiddlyServer authentication dialogue
6. I opened my TiddlyWiki and got the following errors, and found this in the log:

[image]

[image]

[image]

7. As another test, I tried uploading a file using TiddlyServer's upload functionality but was not successful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: On a sidenote, have you looked at noteself.org? I personally use a cheap VPS (512 MB ram would do), and configuration is much more straightforward. You can even install Bob and set up version control using Git.

Comment: Did you get this working?